How to enable <Link> and <a> inside motion.div
I'm applying a slide animation using framer-motion, but inside each slide item there's an <a> tag, but due to the motion it cannot be clicked.
<motion.div
  ref={carrossel}
  className="partners-carrossel"
  whileTap={{ cursor: "grabbing" }}
>
  <motion.div
    className="partners-inner-carrossel"
    drag="x"
    dragConstraints={{ right: 0, left: -carrosselWith }}
  >
    {partners.map((partner) => (
      <PartnerCard
        key={partner.id}
        logo={partner.logo}
        name={partner.name}
        description={partner.description}
        linkText={partner.linkText}
        linkUrl={partner.lunkUrl}
      />
    ))}
  </motion.div>
</motion.div>

PartnerCard
const PartnerCard = ({ logo, name, description, linkText, lunkUrl }) => {
  return (
    <motion.div className="partner-card">
      <img
        draggable="false"
        src={logo}
        alt={`${name} logo`}
        className="partner-logo"
      />
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <p>{description}</p>
      <a
        target="_blank"
        href={lunkUrl}
        rel="noreferrer"
        className="partner-link"
      >
        {linkText}
      </a>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

On this code I apply the motion either on the parent element to act like a carrossel, and on the children to be draggable.
What I want is to enable the <a> tags to be clickable inside the motion tags.
